# What is a good, free database scripting tool

Tags: sql, scripting, insert, generator

I am looking for a free tool that will allow me to specify a SELECT statement on a table and then generate the result set as a series of INSERT statements to transfer to another database.  I have the SQL Publishing Wizard, but that only allows me to generate statements for the entire table, and I can't specify a WHERE clause to filter the data it publishes.  So far the only tool I have seen is made by Red Gate, which my employer only gives to DBA's.  Are there any free tools out there that will let me do the same thing, without having to go and bug a DBA everytime I need to update some data in a database?

Comment: Isn't it like five minute work to write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com) has a good collection of features, including generating insert statements.  Works on MS SQL 2005 and beyond.

Comment: One of my favourites too

Comment: This was perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this one in the past, I don't think its been updated recently:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt